# Как удалить из строки последовательность каких-либо символов заключённых в фигурные скобки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например

```
'I am very {dfghjk} good boy.'
```

Нужно как-то удалить элемент `{dfghjk}`.

Его длина и расположение не имеют значения: он может располагаться в начале или конце строки и состоять из одного и более символов.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
'I am very good boy.'
```

Comment: Могут быть вложенные/несбалансированные элементы? К примеру, какой результат ожидаете для: `"}{{a{b{c}d}e}f"`?

Comment: @jfs Дание с которими я роботаю , не имеют в себе чевото подобного. Поетому я даже не знаю , што ответить:)

Comment: Это значит что вложенных нет скобок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения (`Regular Expressions` [AKA](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Also-Known-As-(AKA).html) `RegEx`):

```
In [120]: import re

In [121]: s
Out[121]: '{Am} I am very {bad} good {girl} boy.'

In [122]: re.sub(r'{[^\}]+}', '', s)
Out[122]: ' I am very  good  boy.'
```

чтобы убрать лишние пробелы:

```
In [125]: re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'{[^\}]+}', '', s)).strip()
Out[125]: 'I am very good boy.'
```

Answer (score 1):

лучше регулярными выражениями, но как вариант

```
def format_from_kwargs(arg: str, **kwargs) -> str:
    try:
        return arg.format(**kwargs)
    except KeyError as ex:
        kwargs[ex.args[0]] = ''
        return format_from_kwargs(arg, **kwargs)

print(format_from_kwargs('I am very {dfghjk} good boy. {qwe}'))
```

Comment: это ломается для `'{error! element}'`. И даже, когда работает для простых строк, мягко говоря, это не рекомендуемая опция (всё равно что обои через замочную скважину клеить).

Answer (score 0):

```
# имеем: str_1='I am very {dfghjk} good boy.' 

list_1=str_1.split()      # преобразуем в список
list_1.remove('{dfghjk}') # удаляем {dfghjk}
str_new=' '.join(list_1)  # объединяем в новую строку
print(str_new)

# ожидаемый результат: I am very good boy.
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, что будет, если между фигурными скобками будет `{abc}`? Будет ли достигнут ожидаемый результат?

Comment: Да. И результат останется ожидаемый.Только во второй строчке естественно запись станет  с двойными фигурными скобками:  list_1.remove('{{abc}}')